# Why are the Dai Li still serving Ba Sing Se?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In Legend of Korra I was wondering but why is the Dai Li still allowed to serve the Queen and Ba Sing Se?

I don't know where I got this idea from but I was under the impression that they were disbanded (?)

How did the Dai Li regain their lost trust after the Last Airbender and how are they still active? Finally does the Dai Li still serve the same role of protecting Ba Sing Se's cultural heritage? What exactly do they do now?

Answer (score 5):

The same reason Donald Rumsfeld and Dick Cheney stayed in government after their "issues" in the 80s, and why most of the KGB became members of the FSB, politics and inertia.

The Dai Li were an integral part of the Earth kingdom hierarchy for hundreds of years dating back to Avatar Kyoshi.  Sure Grand Secretariat Long Feng was able to manipulate it into something that was a threat to the monarchy, but once he was gone the organization remained.  Hou-Ting the current Earth Queen commands them directly, preventing them from being used against the monarchy.  Also, they probably had too much political sway to be dissolved and may have been involved with the selection of Hou-Ting as the Earth Queen.  Looking at Roman history for parallel, the Praetorian Guard would regularly remove emperors and replace them with their own, only to remove them years later.